# How to replace particular value in string with tokens in xslt using replace function

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I have a cookie value something like this :

Cookie :  JSESSIONID:12345678; Rules:adsaafdf123-erefg; ApplicationID:123456.

I wanted to replace Application ID value with some other unique value for each and every call and set it back to the xslt variable.

Ex:

Cookie :  JSESSIONID:12345678; Rules:adsaafdf123-erefg; ApplicationID:234567.

Can someone help me with the proper xslt code.

I have tried regexp, translate and replace with for each on string tokenize functions but couldn't get it.

Comment: _"set it back to the xslt variable."_ is an strange wording in XSLT because variables are immutable. You might get more help if you show your stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
replace($yourString, 'ApplicationID:\d+', 'ApplicationID:234567')
```

Comment: It works for me: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWEaSva

Comment: Works fine for me, Thanks !